# How to align a div in a wrapper with auto width

Tags: css

How can I align a `div` in a wrapper on the right side when the `div` width is auto?

### Example:

```js
$("span").click(function() {
 $(".calendarNotificationWrapper").append("<div class='calendarNotification'>New added notification</div>");
});
```

```css
.calendarNotificationWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1000000;
  text-align: right;
}

.calendarNotification {
  width: auto;
  line-height: 20px;
  z-index: 10000000;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span>Add a notification</span>

<div class="calendarNotificationWrapper">
  <div class="calendarNotification">
    This div should be aligned right
  </div>

  <div class="calendarNotification">
    That is a notification message with a very very long text
  </div>

  <div class="calendarNotification">
    This div should also be aligned right
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/29xosa2u/1/ you mean like that ?

Comment: Please do not link to JSFiddle and instead use the native code embedding tool from StackOverflow. I already edited your question and I am just waiting for the edit to be peer reviewed.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
margin-left:auto;
```

to .calendarNotification

Comment: You can also use float: right; to force it to right align :)

Comment: nah, that was easy :-D